# C# in-place sort on elements that have a defined property

Tags: c#, sorting

Let's imagine I have a list, all elements have an order property except for Element with Id 4:

```
List<Element> elements = new List<Element> {
    new Element {Id = 1, Name = "First", Order = 2}, 
    new Element {Id = 2, Name = "Second", Order = 3}, 
    new Element {Id = 3, Name = "Third", Order = 1}, 
    new Element {Id = 4, Name = "Fourth", Order = null};
```

I need to sort elements in-place based on the **order** property but the element with Id 4 is not taken into consideration as it has order property set to null.

```
public void ModifyList() { 
   Order(elements);

   return elements; // I want to end up with Element Id:3, 
                    // Element Id:1, Element Id:2 and the last 
                    // one Element with Id:4 (it is returned 
                    //   as the last element as the sort did not apply to it.
}

private static void Order(IList<Element> elements) {
   elements.Sort((x, y) => x.Order.CompareTo(y.Order));
}
```

I know that I could first create one list that contains elements that have order property, sort them, and than append to the list which does not have that property, is there a cleaner way to do it. (without using OrderBy()).

Comment: What's the type of `Id`? `int?`?

Comment: It is integer, but I'm ordering by Order property, not id.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Order` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own comparer to ensure that the Nulls go at the end:

```
public sealed class ElementComparer: IComparer<Element>
{
    public int Compare(Element? x, Element? y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, y))
            return 1;

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, x))
            return -1;

        if (x.Order == null)
            return 1;

        if (y.Order == null)
            return -1;

        return x.Order.Value.CompareTo(y.Order.Value);
    }
}
```

Then you can in-place sort the elements in the list like so:

```
 elements.Sort(new ElementComparer());
```

If you try it, you'll see that it's ordered by `.Order` but with any null ones at the end.

One thing to be aware of is that `List<T>.Sort()` is an *unstable* sort, which means that after sorting, the order of items with the same `.Order` (including null ones) is undefined.

`Enumerable.OrderBy()` performs a stable sort.

Comment: I understand it's unstable but I also want to perform in-place sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach(var item in elements.OrderBy( x=> (x.Order is null ? 9999 : x.Order))) {
    System.Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
}
```

Of course you should change the `9999` when the values of `Id` are also in that range...

see: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NYtb67)

Comment: Instead of 9999 I'd use `int.MaxValue`

Comment: Yes, but (bad excuse) that was more typing.... 

Comment: this is cool but I wanted to avoid creating new list, that's why I used sort